# Why is my wifi slow on one pc in my network?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I've a W7 64bit machine in my network and the internet connection is very slow. When I run speedtest.net I get a result of 2-3 Mbps. While on my laptop I get 49-50 Mbps.

My setup:
Both machines (laptop and pc) are in the same space. Both have W7 installed on a 64bit system. Both are only connected through wifi. Both have all the wifi bars colored green.

I've tried to:

- update the wifi driver of the pc (Atheros AR9285)
- Change channel on my router from 1 to 11
- Changed Mode from 11n to 11bgn mixed
- See with inSSIDer if there are any other access points which could interfer with my network. In inSSIDer I see only my own access point. In top right corner, link as a value of 100.

I have

- set security to WPA/WPA2 - Personal on my router
- Enabled WWM
- Enabled Short GI

What else can I try to get my speed back on this machine? It hasn't always be this slow.

Comment: Have you tried booting to another OS (say, a Linux LiveCD) on the problematic computer? If it behave fine, then you have a software problem, if not, then you have a hardware (or environmental) problem.

Comment: No I didn't. I don't have any experience with that. And the problematic pc is a backbone, without a cd player.

Comment: Alright, you can boot form a LiveUSB instead of a disk. :)  Once you've tried that, perhaps edit your question to update it with your results.

Comment: What is the model of the antenna on the PC? Can you find it here http://www.newegg.com/Wireless-Adapters/SubCategory/ID-31? Is it a USB antenna? Are there any obstructions in the way? The PC itself can be an obstruction if the antenna is on the rear and the router is somewhere in front of the PC. Have you tried moving the router and/or PC to different spots? It's possible that the PC antenna doesn't support those speeds. Is the antenna actually screwed onto the WiFi card?

Comment: If there are a lot of other wireless networks close by, there might be some signal overlap going on.  Is there any way to verify what wireless networks are close by and what frequency channels they are using?